# LibreOffice dictionary and spell checking in other languages? (without Java)

Tags: java, language, libreoffice, spell-check, dictionary

Using LibreOffice (latest version) on OS X, everything in English. However I frequently work with documents in other languages (e.g. German, Dutch, French) and I would like to have spell checking for those languages as well.

I googled around but found tons of links that all either became redundant (since older LibreOffice or OpenOffice versions, I guess) or are no longer available. Nothing I try seems to work.

The only thing that looked hopeful was 'LanguageTool' but this extension seems to require installing Java, which I don't want.

What is the best solution to get foreign language support (as in spell checking / dictionary, not user interface) in LibreOffice without forcing me to install Java, and where or how do I go about that exactly?

Comment: LibreOffice requires Java you are not going to get away from that requirement.

Comment: @Ramhound But I'm already using LibreOffice, it works just fine? Just in case: the error I get when installing that LanguageTool extension is "To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment." and the "Could not create Java implementation loader". However, again, my LibreOffice v5.0.2 installation works just fine, and to my knowledge I never installed anything Java related.

Comment: Right, the extension requires it, certain features of LibreOffice require Java.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice is perfect if you deal with multiple languages. You can two possibilities: Either you download the languages packs for each of the languages you need from libreoffice -> download or you just download the relevant dictionaries and hyphenation patterns. An overview is here for about 140 languages: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Language_support_of_LibreOffice

Grammar check is inbuilt for English, Russian, Portuguese and another language (I have forgotten). You can also add the excellent LanguageTool for Grammar Check in over 30 languages: https://languagetool.org/

Answer (score 1):

After searching online on various places and trying several files I found that this Dutch dictionary works for LibreOffice Writer 6.0.5.2:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/aoo-extensions/files/1456/6/nl-dict-v2.00g.oxt/download
(I am aware that it was developed as an extension for OpenOffice though).
After installing I restarted Writer and then it worked fine for me.